# Splitting string in C# using a phrase

Tags: c#

I have a string like this :

```
Phrase-No: 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Phrase-No: 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

and i want to split it in a List like this:

```
Phrase-No: 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Phrase-No: 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

how could I do that with C#? my problem is that I don't know how many Phrases-No there will be inside the string

Comment: How do you do it as a human? Are you looking for "Phrase-No:"? Then do it in C# the same way. Other than that, you already have the word: [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) is quite intuitive, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `string.Split`:

```
var phrases = s.Split("Phrase-No: ");

foreach(var phrase in phrases) Console.WriteLine(phrase);
```

This produces:

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

If you wish to catch the numbers and the phrases then Regex is here to help:

```
// [ ]* is to remove the extra space in after each phrase
string pattern = @"[ ]*Phrase-No: ([0-9]+) ";

//Because our string starts with the pattern the first match will be ''
var found = Regex.Split(s, pattern).Skip(1).ToList();

for(int i=0; i < found.Count(); i+=2) Console.WriteLine($"String {found[i]} is '{found[i+1]}'");
```

```
String 1 is 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
String 2 is 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex. Looks complicated but is worth learning it when you regularly have to deal with text.

```
string foo = "Phrase-No: 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Phrase-No: 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
// Split after every char = ".", but only when I look ahead in the string (?=   ) and see "Phrase-No: <digit>"  
string[] bar = Regex.Split(foo, @".(?=Phrase\-No: \d)");
```

Comment: You don't need `.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Used hundreds of times but never thought to leave out the dot

Comment: Tested it, you need the dot,otherwise you have an empty further element at index 0. With the dot it starts splitting after first char. Without before first char.

Answer (score -4):

Try Using `String.Split()`
Documentation for Split String

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads

OR USE
REGEX.SPLIT

Use Code

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");

foreach (string sentence in sentences) {
  Console.WriteLine(sentence);
}
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Comment: You mention one method and use a completely different one

Comment: Linking to String.Split() and then using Regex.Split() does not match. Using Regex is overkill here. And what does the Regex mean? How can this Regex ever get rid of "Phrase No:"?

Comment: You can use either one

Comment: The same result can be achieved with just `.Split("Phrase-No: ")`. The desired result though includes `Phrase-No: `, which means one can't just use a simple `Split`, or this regular expression.